# Implementing a function to wait for user input in existing code

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently expanding the functionality of an existing program.
My addition is supposed to stop the main function of the program when an error is found to enable the user to fix the error and then continue the main function.

The problem I do have now is that I do not know how I can implement a "wait function" to stop the main function until a user input through tkinter is given.
Additionally I want to ask if there is an alternative to mainloop(), for example to only refresh the ui once every main function loop

I'm an engineer and no programmer so sorry for messy code and the lack of proper terminology.

My implementation so far:

In the main function:

```
if Total_Errors != 0:

  os.startfile(root)
  Error_Window(root)
```

Outside of main function:

```
def Error_Window(root):

  import tkinter

  ErrorWindow = tkinter.Tk()
  ErrorWindow.title("Error found")
  ErrorWindow.resizable(0,0)
  tkinter.Label(ErrorWindow, text="Error fount at:").pack(padx=10, pady=0)
  tkinter.Label(ErrorWindow, text=root,).pack(padx=10, pady=0)
  tkinter.Button(ErrorWindow, text="Ignore", command=PlaceHolder).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
  tkinter.Button(ErrorWindow, text="Continue", command=PlaceHolder).pack(padx=10, pady=10) 
  ErrorWindow.mainloop()
```

Please do give constructive criticism on how my question can be improved.

Comment: When is `Total_Errors` calculated?

Comment: *"to stop the `main function` until a user input through tkinter is given"*: Read about `.wait_window(...)` using [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm)

Comment: @Guimoute  Total_Errors is calculated as a result of multiple functions which get executed in a linear style in one long for loop. My code is at the end (still inside) of the for loop to check if user input is required because an error is occurred during one iteration of a loop.

Comment: @stovfl the .wait_window function did exactly solve my problems thank you a lot!
If you want to post it as an answer I will mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @GittingGud: Go ahead and write the answer with the code part of your solution. Include the reference to [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the method of .wait_window using [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) suggested by @stovfl I was able to solve my problem:

I implemented the whole "ErrorWindow" into the main function for loop with the code snippet looking like this:

```
if Total_Errors != 0:

    ErrorWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(Window)
    ErrorWindow.title("Error")
    ErrorWindow.minsize(width=250, height=250)
    ErrorWindow.resizable(0,0)

    tkinter.Label(ErrorWindow, text="Error found at:").pack()
    tkinter.Label(ErrorWindow, text=root).pack()

    tkinter.Button(ErrorWindow,text="Continue", command=ErrorWindow.destroy).pack()

    os.startfile(root)
    Window.wait_window(ErrorWindow)
```